# Maven retains older version of asm in repository

Tags: java, maven

Initially, I had the maven dependency for asm version 3.2 in pom.xml file of my project. I update the same to version 4.1 using the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but now my project has both jar files in WEB-INF/lib - asm 3.2 and asm 4.1. I need some features of asm 4.1 but due to both jars being available asm 3.2 code is used because of which I cannot use the asm 4.1 feature.

Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dependency for `asm` 3.2 is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note the group IDs do not match.  What is likely happening is that another of your dependencies is loading `asm` 3.2 as a transitive dependency.  Maven's dependency resolution process cannot determine that the 4.1 version is supposed to override the 3.2 version due to the group ID difference, and there is a problem.

What you need to do is eliminate the 3.2 version.  First figure out which dependency is causing Maven to pull it in, by running `mvn dependency:tree` or using the Eclipse POM editor's dependency hierarchy tab.  Then find that dependency in your POM and add an exclusion:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency-pulling-in-asm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

[Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) explains this further.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following command after updating pom.xml

```
mvn clean
```

Comment: There is here a groupId conflict between 2 versions of asm. mvn clean won't sort it out.