# Maven dependency order in Eclipse causing error

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am using Eclipse m2e plugin 1.4.0. I have a Maven project that depends on another jar, which also depends on many other external libraries. Eclipse is complaining about my source code because some external APIs are not correct.

The cause of this is the external libraries are depending on different versions of the same external library (e.g. slf4j). Although I have that managed in my parent pom, where I can compile my project without errors using mvn, Eclipse m2e is still complaining because the libraries order in the classpath is not correct (the managed version is listed later in the list, while an older version is included in one of the libraries).

Is there any way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18920052/944849) recently, describing how to find which dependency is pulling in the unwanted library and exclude it.

Comment: Another thing you can do is run `mvn clean install` on the parent POM to ensure it is in your local repository for Eclipse to find.

Comment: Hi, I ended up adding the required dependency once again (although that is in the parent pom already) to the top of other dependencies in my project. This is ugly, because mvn is totally fine, just the Eclipse m2e plugin...grrrh.

Comment: When you added the dependency in the parent, did you put it in `<dependencies>` or `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: `<dependencyManagement>`